# How do I use JavaScript to open another window in the web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, beagleboard

I'm working with a webserver on the Beagleboard. The server was made in cherrypy and I want to create a login page to authenticate to another webpage.

I am using the following HTML/JavasScript code that I found on the Internet:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Login page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Simple Login Page
</h1>
<form name="login">
Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
/*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
{
window.open('pag.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
}
else
{
alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I receive the following error:
`NotFound: (404, "The path '/home/root/webserver/pag.html' was not found.")`

Comment: Maybe because it's page.html or something?

Comment: Does the file `/home/root/webserver/pag.html` exist?

Answer (score 1):

try this in this code you can specify height width of the new window also

```
<INPUT type="button" value="New Window!" onClick="window.open('http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jex5.htm','mywindow','width=400,height=200')">
```